# Scrapy Xpath Selectors won't work on some expressions

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

When I use the scrapy shell (or when running the crawler) some expressions seem to not work:

```
scrapy shell http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-02-17/climate-change-could-threaten-entire-financial-system-apra/8281436?section=business
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler ...
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> # That's working:
>>> Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="article section"]/h1/text()').extract()[0]
u'Climate change could threaten entire financial system, APRA warns'
>>> # But this is not:
>>> Selector(response).xpath('//p[@class="first"]/text()').extract()
[]
```

What am I doing wrong? Chromium Dev Tools are able to find the XPath expression but my Python script not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if you open the website in your browser, and view its source, or download its source using 'wget' or 'curl', you cannot find a 'p' tag with 'first' as its class.

The 'first' class attribute may be appended to a 'p' tag by javascript, so you can find it using Chromium Dev Tools.